# If USA B-1 visa stamping is done for 6 months, can we stay more than 90 days on business trip?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, b1-b2-visas

If USA B-1 visa stamping is done for 6 months, can we stay more than 90 days on business trip?

I heard that it's advisable not to stay more than 90 days on a business trip. is it a myth?

if exceeded 90 days but not 180:

1. What is the impact of re-entry?
2. Does it have an impact while applying any other work visa in future?

Any experiences or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Visa validity is 10 years and stamp on passport is 6 months

Answer (score 13):

The number of days listed on your visa is the visa validity: this is the period during which you can use the visa to enter the US. [How long you can stay in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_visa#Validity_period_and_duration_of_stay) is determined by Customs and Border Protection at the border based on "the period necessary to carry out your business activities." If you're not sure how long this period is (normally, check the stamp in your passport), you can [check your I-94 online](https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov/I94/). You must leave the US (or [apply for an extension](https://www.uscis.gov/visit-united-states/extend-your-stay) well before this date) before your status runs out. If you're admitted to the US for six months, then you're permitted to stay for six months.

That said, long stays can invite more suspicion. You can only use a business visa for [certain purposes](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/BusinessVisa%20Purpose%20Listings%20March%202014%20flier.pdf), but you cannot use one to live or work in the United States. Since many business visitors come for relatively short conferences or meetings, you may face more questions to assess whether you're really only going to be doing what you're allowed to do. Repeated long trips can raise even more suspicion.

If you do have a permitted business reason to stay more than 90 days, it's a good idea to have a clear explanation and supporting documents (indeed, it's a good idea even if you're staying for 12 hours). For example, proof you're attending a four month training program or that you're a service engineer repairing industrial equipment on a job that will take five months (within the bounds of what is permitted for foreign service engineers to do).

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply.. Just to shed more light: VISA validity is 10 Years.. stamp on the passport is 6 months

Comment: @AY visa is a normal word.  There's no reason to write it in all caps.

Comment: *it's a good idea even if you're staying for 12 hours* - yes. From experience such short stays were frowned upon and I was extensively questionned (I was routinely travelling to the US from Europe for 3-4 days stays, once a month or so - and a few times just for a few hours). At one of these questionings I ended up telling them that I am staying 24 hours because I could not sqeeze my stay to 10 hours, which would be better seeing at how I felt welcome in that country. This ended the questionning but could have also have me deported (which would not have been a great loss, in perspective)

Comment: @WoJ You'd need to answer in all future visa applications "Have you ever been deported" with "yes" - not a great loss, really?

Comment: @FooBar well, it depends on the perspective. I am French, living in France. I used to spend a seizable part of my life in the US and hated the travel. It's been now 10 years I haven't been there and I am fine. So if the country I worked for and spent my money in makes all my entries miserable, be it. The US will not miss me, and I would not miss the US. I may go in a few years for vacation with my kids but I am not particularly thrilled by the idea. It's a shame because such behavior at the border just make people like me give up (and I would go there to only spend money)

Comment: @WoJ You'd have to answer that question with "Yes" for any country that you will apply a visa for, not only US.

Comment: @WoJ They ask you those questions because it's very difficult to deport you after you've been admitted, _unless you lied in order to gain admission_. You're not expected ever to answer the questions in the affirmative, but it makes it easy to deport you if it turns out that you _were_ a Nazi.

Comment: @MikeScott: thanks - I expected this to have a legal aspect rather than a defferent one where the bandit-in-spe would be arrested because he would frankly affirm his will to misbehave.

Answer (score 5):

> is it a myth?

Yes!

Wish I could write more, but that's all there's to it really. If you get 6 months, then you can stay for 6 months. Period.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, but will there be any side-effects of stay specifically after 90 days?

Comment: @AY There is no 90 day limit if entering on a B1 Visa, unless the CBP officer has stamped to allow only 90 days.  Under ESTA Visa Waiver you have max 90 days, but with a B1 Visa the ESTA VWP does not apply.